# TypeError: setauth is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am newbie in react-router-dom and facing this issue for first time! 
Whenever I Click on Logout Button on Homs.js File it gives me following error: `TypeError: setauth is not a function` 
auth will be set true from **login** as well as **signup** function 
**Tysm for helping in advance!** 
**App.js**

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';

//import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route ,Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Login from './components/Login';
import SignUp from './components/SignUp';
import ViewAllCustomers from './components/ListCustomer';
import AllTransactions from './components/Transactions';




const App = (props) => {

  const [auth,setAuth] = useState(false);

  const setauth = boolean => {
    setAuth(boolean);
  };

  return (<div >
      <Router>
        <Switch>          
          <Route exact path="/" 
          render ={ props => !auth?(<Home {...props} seauth={setauth}/>):(<Redirect to="/login" />) }
          />           
          
          <Route path="/login"
          render = {props => !auth?(<Login {...props} seAuth={setauth} />):(<Redirect to="/" />)} />
          
          <Route path="/signup"
          render = {props => !auth?(<SignUp {...props} setAuth={setauth}/>):(<Redirect to="/" />)} 
          />
          
          <Route path="/customer">
            <ViewAllCustomers />
          </Route>          

          <Route path="/transfers">
            <AllTransactions />
          </Route>

        </Switch>
    </Router>        
  </div>);
}

export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from'react';
const Home = ({ setauth }) => {

    const logout = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setauth(false);
    }

    return (<div className="container">
        <h1>
            Home Page            
        </h1>
        <button className="btn btn-danger mt-5" onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
        </div>);
}

export default Home;
```

**Tysm for helping in advance!**
[image: ss]

auth will be set true from **login** as well as **signup** function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass `seauth={setauth}`, but in Home.js you still use `setauth`. Either fix grammar mistakes or use `seauth` in Home.js

Edit: Adding to my answer, you should really use camelCase or snake_case throughout your project, as it improves readability.

Comment: What should happen when you execute the `setauth` function?

Comment: It should Logout and go to Login.js File!

Comment: Then redirect the user to the login page. You only change the state but it does not seem to have an effect on the location of the user. You should probably have a `useEffect` with `auth` dep and redirect user to login if `auth` is false in your case.